# Django - Query on a TimeField, how to compare times?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models

I have a Model in a Django application that looks like this

```
class Flight(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length = 15, primary_key = True)
    airline = models.ForeignKey(Airline)
    departure_airport = models.ForeignKey(Airport, related_name='flight_departure')
    departure_time = models.TimeField()
    arriving_airport = models.ForeignKey(Airport, related_name='flight_arriving')
    arriving_time = models.TimeField()
    aircraft = models.ForeignKey(Aircraft)
```

I now would like to retrieve only the flights that depart after the current time.  For this, I have tried the following on the console:

```
from datetime import *
time = datetime.time(datetime.now())
f = Flight.objects.filter(departure_time > time)
```

After running the previous statements I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'departure_time' is not defined
```

Also, if I try the following I also get a similar error:

```
f = Flight.objects.filter(departure_time > '12:00:00')
```

However, this works:

```
f = Flight.objects.filter(departure_time = '12:00:00')
print f
[<Flight: LH17>]
```

I would be very thankful if somebody could provide advise on how to compare (query) times on a TimeField field?

Thanks.

Comment: For anyone looking for further advise, check this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#id4)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem isn't with the fact that it's a time field, your problem is that you're not giving `filter` a field lookup.  You'd get the same kind of error if you were trying to make that kind of query on an integer field.

Django queries aren't expressed using Python comparison operators like `<`, `>`, or `==`.  Instead, they're (usually) expressed using a keyword syntax to which you then bind values using the assignment operator `=`.

Your query should be:

```
f = Flight.objects.filter(departure_time__gt=time)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#field-lookups has the full details.